# Cardinality of order topology?

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics, order-topology

Just out of interest: The cardinality of the Euclidean topology on the real line is $c$. In general, if $X$ is totally ordered of cardinality $\alpha$, the order topology on $X$ must have cardinality $\geq\alpha$. When is it precisely $\alpha$?

Comment: Interesting question. One thing of note is that if $O$ is an infinite ordinal, then the order topology induced by the usual order has cardinality $2^{|O|}$, given that any set $S\subseteq O$ containing no limit ordinals is open. (And, if $O$ is a limit ordinal, the map $f(x)=x+1$ is a bijection between $O$ and the elements of $O$ which are not limit ordinals)

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate.

Why is the topology on $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$? Because we have a basis of size $\aleph_0$ and each open set is the union of $\aleph_0$ basic open sets.

So if $(X,\leq)$ is a linear order, then its order topology has size $\leq\kappa$ if (and only if) there exists a basis of size $\mu$ such that every open set is the union of at most $\lambda$ basic open sets, and $\mu^\lambda\leq\kappa$.

Some observations:

1. $|X|\leq\mu^\lambda$.
2. We can assume $\lambda\leq\mu$, since any union of more than $\mu$ elements of a set of size $\mu$, is really just the same union of at most $\mu$ elements.

So if $|X|=\mu^\lambda$ then the topology is exactly the wanted size.

Comment: But this works for any $T_0$-topology, right? Can we use the fact that the topology comes from a linear order (and hence is completely normal Hausdorff) to obtain information on $\mu$ or $\lambda$?